# How to redirect to another view from a partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app, I have an search form in my _Layout.cshtml.

When the form is submitted, I have a jquery function that gets called, and properly goes to my SearchController, executes all the proper code, but I'm never brought to the correct page, whatever current page I'm on just gets refreshed.

Right now if I manually go to /Search?q=query it will show fine, but my Action method returning

```
return View("Index", new SearchViewModel())
```

doesn't do anything from my **jQuery** `.post()` call.

Comment: do you need return partialview("Index", model)?

Comment: No, I want it to completely redirect me to /Search/Index

Comment: do you use a form in your layout? if so, please add to your post

Comment: Try return RedirectResult(url)l

Comment: **doesn't do anything from my jQuery post call**... are you attempting an ajax post? and a redirect from there?

Comment: Oh you can't redirect from an ajax post or get.. you must do so on the callback. Try window.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doesn't do anything from my jQuery post call
```

- For starters you CANNOT Redirect from a JQuery Post (AJAX call)

You will want to use the return value to make a `window.location='{url}'` call

- Why would you want to use an Ajax call like JQuery Post? Why not make your call a real Post?

From there you can return a View, RedirectToAction, etc.

Your options would increase greatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
return PartialView ("Index", new SearchViewModel())
```

Comment: Bilal, how do you interpret the OP's intent and obstacle? Do you feel that this syntax would resolve the problem?